# Rails rspec render_template error

Tags: rspec3, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm following Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and can't figure out why the following code keep on giving me this error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template("membres/show")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass
```

The code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Membres", :type => :request do  

  include Capybara::DSL

  describe "une inscription" do
    describe "ratée" do
      it "ne devrait pas créer un nouvel utilisateur" do
        visit signup_path
        fill_in "Nom",          :with => ""
        fill_in "Email",        :with => ""
        fill_in "Password",     :with => ""
        fill_in "Confirmation", :with => ""
        click_button "Inscription"
        expect(response).to render_template("membres/show")
        expect(response).to have_tag("div#error_explanation")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I tryied using "page" instead of "response" on the line in error, I also tryied other link instead of "membres/show" but nothing does it.

Anyone have any idea at this point?

**Edit**

It's definitly "page" i should use instead of "response" but that still doesn't clear out the error message.

Comment: Could it be that I cannot use render_template in a requests spec?

Comment: I think `render_template` is more suited to controller specs

Comment: Would that be new as of Rails 4? Because the tutorial I follow says to put that test in a requests spec and that tutorial is about Rails 3.

Comment: sorry, i mixed this with feature spec, anyways, i still think you won't get a response object without running a `get` or `post` request, the second expect makes sense, but after replacing `response` with `page` like you said, the first expect should be moved to a user controller spec to work

Comment: I found out something. It says [here](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.2/rspec-rails/#render_template) that render_template should work in request spec in rspec 3.2 which is my version. It also says that render_template uses rails's function assert_template. I'm gonna inquire there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to solve that problem.

Look in your error message for the path of "test_case.rb" and for the line in error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:111:in `assert_template'
     # ./spec/requests/membres_spec.rb:21:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/membres_spec.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

In my case the file is located at "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/" and the line in error is 111.

With your favourite text editor, open "test_case.rb" as root, go to the line specified it should look like this:

```
response.body
```

Change it to:

```
response.body if !response.nil?
```

And you should  be able to use render_template or assert_template without using:

```
get
```

or

```
post
```

In my case, I can use

```
visit
```

Which doesn't create a "response" object thus the error message.